# Higher/Lower Game: ValueError

Tags: python

For my scripting class, we have to make a higher/lower game. This is my code so far:

```
import random

seedVal = int(input("What seed should be used? "))
random.seed(seedVal)
lower = int(input("What is the lower bound? "))
upper = int(input("What is the upper bound? "))
number = random.randint(lower, upper)

while (True):
    guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
    if(number < lower or number > upper):
        print("The number should be between the upper bound and the lower bound")
    elif(guess == number):
        print("You got it!")
        break
    elif(guess < number):
        print("Nope, too low.")
    else:
        print("Nope, too high.")
```

It has worked for 3/4 functionality tests however it fails when I input:
2
5
1
1
5
1
2
3
4
5

The error it gives me is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HigherLowerGame.py", line 7, in <module>
    number = random.randint(lower, upper)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 248, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 226, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (5, 2, -3)
```

Comment: In `random.randint(start, end)`, the first number should be smaller than the second number. When you pass `lower=5`, and `upper=1`, the `randint` would fail. Use `random.randint(min_num, max_num)` from the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check if `lower` is greater than `upper`. You can also use `min`/`max` to take the lowest and highest value:

```
lower = int(input("What is the lower bound? "))
upper = int(input("What is the upper bound? "))
number = random.randint(min(lower, upper), max(lower, upper))
```

Answer (score 2):

I know practically nothing about python but with that input sequence it sounds like you're asking randint to generate a random number where the lower bound is 4 and the upper bound is 1 and that's not possible.